# Looking for Adam Gould and Rachel Burkholder in 18th/19th century Pennsylvania?

Tags: 19th-century, 18th-century, marriage-records, pennsylvania

I can find a later Adam Gould and Rachel Burkholder in McKeesport but I am looking for an earlier couple that may have lived in Westmoreland County PA.

They would be the parents of the Adam in McKeesport and he would be the child of Abraham Gould b.1766 and Ann Osborn b.1768.

The Adam I'm looking for was b.1789 to Abraham and Ann. Adam was born in eastern PA and died in western PA 1851. Rachel Burkholder was b. 1790 and died in Peoria, Il 1861.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  What is/are the record(s) that you are using to provide the birth date, location and parents of Adam above?  It is from these that I think you should try to focus your question on another specific piece of information that you are seeking about Adam like how to find his marriage record to Rachel(?).

Comment: Is this the record that you are using as your source information? "Find A Grave Index," database, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QVGN-JX2L : 13 December 2015), Adam Gould, ; Burial, , , ,, ; citing record ID 127176890, Find a Grave, http://www.findagrave.com.  If so, I think it should be included in your question which you can do by using the [edit] button beneath it.

Comment: It would be useful to know which record sources you've already searched.

Comment: I've used ancestry and visited the County Records in Greensburg PA. I've looked at census records finding one Adam Gould that may coorespond to the Adam I'm looking for living in Mifflin PA which could be today's West Mifflin. His child Adam Gould lived in McKeesport not too far away. The younger Adam was a Blacksmith first then moved to mill work in later years. I wondered if older Adam had been a blacksmith too.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! It would be useful to have a list of the source documents you already have, listed in chronological order. This allows people to review what you've already seen at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

My mother grew up on Brookhill farm in Plymouth Meeting Montgomery County Pa.
I understand the owners of the farm were Zimmerman's of Phila. Electric Co.

The woman who raised her and ran the farm was named Ada Gould she may have been born in the 1880s she later married ?? Schramm. approximately 1935-9.

I know that there was a brother James Gould who lived in Mount Airy Phila. and a sister in law in Chestnut Hill, Pa.

I have photos of the Farm and the children, animals and Ada's wedding.